# Python + Selenium + Chromedriver every page is messed up black pixels missing text even developertools is without text

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Running Python Selenium with Chromedriver is not working, my screenshots shows how it looks now, i dont know why

OS is MACOSX Latest Version (High Sierra)

i just do:

---

```
options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.set_window_size(1400, 800)
driver.delete_all_cookies()
driver.get("https://google.de")
```

---

i already tried to fix it myself with:

reinstalled python through brew

uninstalled miniconda

uninstalled virtuelenv

uninstalled chrome

installed chrome

replaced chromedriver with latest one

used a custom chromedriver from custom chrome folder

---

Opening ***normally*** Chrome 
not through python selenium works without any issue

(btw geckodriver is working, i don't know what happened im running everything now without problems for 5 months something happened that it got fucked )

---

HOW IT LOOKS WITH PYTHON CODE:

[image]

[image]

HOW IT RUNS OPEN CHROME NORMAL MANUALLY:
[image]
[image]

Comment: What is your question , what code have you tried so far ? consider adding HTML , and update the question with error trace ?

Comment: added running code, i don't understand your question, seems like my question is also not presice enough.

i did not blanked out the pictures, that is originally how it looks when running the short code added above and i cannot figure out why my chrome looks like that when running it through selenium chromedriver

Comment: Yes you question is not clear to me. You want to open chrome browser then navigate to google.com and then ?? what do you want to do ?

Comment: i simplified the code, i have no problem with coding, my problem is that even opening google.com does not show the website how it should, even the developer tools are white and shown like in the pictures. What i mean is that chrome is bugged / chromedriver is bugged i can't solve it. I again updated my question now, hope its now more understandable

Comment: Are you facing problem while capturing screenshots ?

Comment: i found the solution, and it seems that it is a bug somewhere in chromedriver / chrome or selenium i don't know but i posted the solution after 12 hours of uninstalling and playing around because even after deleting all that could have the bug still seems that the setting for this left somewhere hidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i found the solution

if you set this preference wrong:

```
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {'intl.accept_languages': 'nl_NL'})
```

you **HAVE** to overwrite it with a correct language value.
like this:

```
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {'intl.accept_languages': 'nl'})
```

This preference seems to stay saved somewhere and is always active even if deleting the line, its active until you overwrite it with a correct language value.
Even uninstalling chrome, chromedrive, selenium, python and install them from scratch this wrong value was active when running my code.

seems like only overwriting it with a new correct value, chrome forces to reload